# How to plot Compressibility factor Z vs Pressure P using ParametricPlot?

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions, chemistry

I am trying to get my plot to look like this:
[image: Z vs P]

but I cannot seem to get it right when I try to plot each curve as a parametric equation. Here is what I have been trying:

```
 ParametricPlot[{{v/(v - 0.0043067) - 0.23026/(8.3144598*(180)*v), (
8.3144598*(180))/(v - 0.0043067) - 0.23026/v^2}, {v/(
v - 0.0043067) - 0.23026/(8.3144598*(189)*v), (8.3144598*(189))/(
v - 0.0043067) - 0.23026/v^2}, {v/(v - 0.0043067) - 0.23026/(
8.3144598*(190)*v), (8.3144598*(190))/(v - 0.0043067) - 0.23026/
v^2}, {v/(v - 0.0043067) - 0.23026/(8.3144598*(200)*v), (
8.3144598*(200))/(v - 0.0043067) - 0.23026/v^2}, {v/(
v - 0.0043067) - 0.23026/(8.3144598*(250)*v), (8.3144598*(250))/(
v - 0.0043067) - 0.23026/v^2}}, {v, 1, 2}]
```

In all honesty, I don't know what the range on `v` should be, since it is the molar volume. On each equation, the temperature in Kelvin is already in.

Comment: For compressibility I used the van der waals equation and solved for Z in terms of molar volume (Z=v/(v-b)-a/RTv) and for pressure I also used the van der waals equation and solved for pressure in terms of molar volume (P=RT/(v-b)-a/v^2). I tried to use both equations in the parametric plot but I might be going about it all wrong.

Comment: Also this plot is for methane at 180 K, 189 K, 190 K, 200 K, and 250 K. The van der Waals parameters for methane are a=2.3026 and b=0.043067

Answer (score 9):

The plot you were trying to reproduce is a plot of the reduced [van der Waals equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_equation); that is, it is using the reduced pressure $P_r=\frac{P}{P_c}$ and reduced temperature $T_r=\frac{T}{T_c}$ as the independent variables. Thus you need to use the reduced form

$$Z=\frac38\left(\frac{8V_r}{3V_r-1}-\frac3{V_r T_r}\right)$$

where $V_r$ is obtained from solving the equation

$$P_r=\frac{8T_r}{3V_r-1}-\frac3{V_r^2}$$

Note that the constants $a$ and $b$ in the conventional presentation are absent, having been absorbed into the critical constants.

Thus,

```
With[{tlist = {1., 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.5, 2.}},
     Plot[Table[With[{v = Root[-3 + 9 #1 - (p + 8 t) #1^2 + 3 p #1^3 &, 1]},
                     3/8 ((8 v)/(3 v - 1) - 3/(t v))], {t, tlist}] // Evaluate,
          {p, 0, 7}, Axes -> None, Frame -> True, 
          FrameLabel -> {"Reduced Pressure (\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(r\)]\))",
                         "Compressibility Factor (Z)"}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
          PlotLegends -> tlist, PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image: compressibility factor for reduced van der Waals equation]

---

Here is a 3D version as a bonus:

```
Plot3D[With[{v = Root[-3 + 9 #1 - (p + 8 t) #1^2 + 3 p #1^3 &, 1]}, 
            3/8 ((8 v)/(3 v - 1) - 3/(t v))], {p, 0, 7}, {t, 0.9, 2.1}, 
       AxesLabel -> {"(\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(r\)]\))", 
                     "(\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(t\), \(r\)]\))", "Z"}, 
      BoundaryStyle -> None, Mesh -> {{1., 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.5, 2.}}, 
      MeshFunctions -> (#2 &), PlotStyle -> Opacity[1/2, ColorData[97, 1]]]
```

[image: compressibility factor surface]

Comment: Awesome feedback! Is there any way to get a plot of Z vs P without using the reduced van der waals equation? Or in other words, plot Z against P for methane (a=2.3026 dm^6 bar mol^-2 and b=0.043067 dm^3 mol^-1) using only the van der waals equation by solving for Z and P?

Comment: Next time, you could be more descriptive with your questions; I shouldn't have had to guess that you were using vdW. Anyway: an explicit expression for molar volume would go something like `With[{r = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "MolarGasConstant"]]]/100, a = 2.3026, b = 0.043067}, Root[-a b + a # - (b p + r t) #^2 + p #^3 &, 1]]`, which you can now plug into vdW.

Comment: Ok, sorry for the ambiguity, I am still new to all of this. So using     With[{r = 
   QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "MolarGasConstant"]]]/
    100, a = 2.3026, b = 0.043067}, 
 Root[-a b + a # - (b p + r t) #^2 + p #^3 &, 1]] how would one end up with the plot of Z vs P?

Comment: Did you notice that the function supplied is now only dependent on `p` and `t`? Replace the molar volume in your compressibility factor expression with this, and you now have $Z$ as a function of $P$ and $T$.

Comment: Makes sense. The only problem I still have is translating that into mathematica language. Could I just plot that function on its own as a list of functions with different values of T and have it depend on P?

Answer (score 0):

Well it's messy but I figured it out. I used solve to solve the van der Waals equation for z and then plotted it.

```
With[{tlist = {180, 189, 190, 200, 250}}, 
 Plot[Table[
With[{r = 
   QuantityMagnitude[
     UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "MolarGasConstant"]]]/100, 
  a = 2.3026, b = 0.043067}, (-b p r^2 t^2 - r^3 t^3)/(
  3 r^3 t^3) - (2^(
     1/3) (3 a p r^4 t^4 - (-b p r^2 t^2 - 
         r^3 t^3)^2))/(3 r^3 t^3 (18 a b p^2 r^6 t^6 + 
       2 b^3 p^3 r^6 t^6 - 9 a p r^7 t^7 + 6 b^2 p^2 r^7 t^7 + 
       6 b p r^8 t^8 + 
       2 r^9 t^9 + \[Sqrt]((18 a b p^2 r^6 t^6 + 
            2 b^3 p^3 r^6 t^6 - 9 a p r^7 t^7 + 
            6 b^2 p^2 r^7 t^7 + 6 b p r^8 t^8 + 2 r^9 t^9)^2 + 
          4 (3 a p r^4 t^4 - (-b p r^2 t^2 - r^3 t^3)^2)^3))^(
     1/3)) + 1/(
   3 2^(1/3)
     r^3 t^3) (18 a b p^2 r^6 t^6 + 2 b^3 p^3 r^6 t^6 - 
     9 a p r^7 t^7 + 6 b^2 p^2 r^7 t^7 + 6 b p r^8 t^8 + 
     2 r^9 t^9 + \[Sqrt]((18 a b p^2 r^6 t^6 + 
          2 b^3 p^3 r^6 t^6 - 9 a p r^7 t^7 + 6 b^2 p^2 r^7 t^7 + 
          6 b p r^8 t^8 + 2 r^9 t^9)^2 + 
        4 (3 a p r^4 t^4 - (-b p r^2 t^2 - r^3 t^3)^2)^3))^(
   1/3)], {t, tlist}] // Evaluate, {p, 0, 700}, Axes -> None, 
Frame -> True, PlotLegends -> tlist, PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image: Z vs P]

Comment: Try this: `With[{r = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "MolarGasConstant"]]]/100, a = 2.3026, b = 0.043067, tlist = {180, 189, 190, 200, 250}}, Plot[Table[With[{v = Root[-a b + a # - (b p + r t) #^2 + p #^3 &, 1]}, v/(v - b) - a/(r t v)], {t, tlist}] // Evaluate, {p, 0, 700}, Axes -> None, Frame -> True, PlotLegends -> tlist, PlotRange -> All]]`.